# Json output not consistent between Bash and Ksh when sending as parameters

Tags: json, bash, ksh

At my current job I am having to learn and interact a lot with Korn Shell

I was having a strange issue that I just learned is related to the differences of Bash and Ksh. Bellow you will see the difference in the output of this command.
With bash I get a json, dictionary like output with Curly Braces in the beginning and end.
With Ksh the Curly Braces are not present in the echo command and that breaks my code later on, as I'm expecting a json to be parsed.

This behavior is consistent to what I'm getting in my next file, where I can't parse the json.

token.sh

```
access_token_response=$(curl -i -k --tlsv1.2 -X POST https://api.cloud.com/oauth2/token -d client_id=id -d client_secret=secret -d grant_type=client_credentials)

echo $access_token_response
```

Outputs

```
$ bash token.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   643    0   516  100   127  23329   5741 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 30619
 {"issued_at":1654531548,"access_token":"eyJlbmMiO5yrqw","expires_in":1296000,"token_type":"Bearer"}
$ ksh token.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   643    0   516  100   127  19549   4811 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 24730
 "issued_at":1654531553 "access_token":"eyJlwMFlKCv7KjEw" "expires_in":1296000 "token_type":"Bearer"
[awsgfedsbtch@ip-204-56-124 shell]$
```

I would love to get a solution for this issue, otherwise I may have to write some strange hacks to get over it.

But what I really want is some sort of guide on how to know and deal with this differences. I don't see that much material about Ksh around and knowing how to bridge the gap between the 2 shells would help me a lot in the long run.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why ksh would behave differently here... unless you set `IFS` to something unusual (which can cause all sorts of trouble). Anyway, the first thing to do is double-quote the variable (`echo "$access_token_response"`) because [unquoted variables get parsed in weird ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) in most shells (basically all except zsh).

Comment: You should use `printf` instead of `echo`, and double-quote your variable expansions

Comment: Ok, that does fix the echo issue, but it doesn't fix it when passing the variable to another file as a parameter...

Comment: `./otherfile.sh "$access_token_response"` should pass it verbatim

Comment: @ACampos Did you double-quote it when passing it as a parameter? Also, just for the record, had you changed `IFS`?